# QNetworkReply segfaults randomly when I invoke `QIODevice::readAll()`, usually something to do with corrupted Data. Is this because it is still open?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am having a real hard time tracking down this bug.
Here is the basic example; It requires a fast connectiona and many simultaneous downloads. When it hits, is fairly random.

```cpp
#ifndef DOWNLOAD_H
#define DOWNLOAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QFile>

class Download : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Download( const QString &path, QUrl url, QObject* parent = nullptr )
    : QThread(parent)
    , f_Local(path)
    , m_Url(url)
    {
        this->start();
    };

private:
    QFile f_Local;
    const QUrl m_Url;

    void run() override
    {
        QNetworkRequest request( m_Url );
        QNetworkAccessManager nam;
        QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);
        {
            reply->setParent(&nam);
        }

        QEventLoop waitForDownload;
        connect( reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, [this, &reply](){
            if ( !f_Local.open(  QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append  ) ) {
                return;
            }
            f_Local.write( reply->readAll() );
            f_Local.close();
            qDebug()
            << f_Local.fileName()
            << Qt::endl
            << f_Local.size() << "/"
            << reply->header( QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader ).toLongLong()
            << Qt::endl
            << m_Url.toDisplayString()
            << Qt::endl;
        });
        connect( reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &waitForDownload, &QEventLoop::quit );
        waitForDownload.exec();
    }
};

#endif // DOWNLOAD_H
```

[This is a gdb trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOH6C.png) and it shows that some corruption is occurring when QNetworkReply is trying to free its cache

The important thing to note, is that I am calling `readAll()` on `readyRead()` as opposed to `finished()`, meaning it is still capable of writing data to the `QNetworkReply` object. Would this perhaps be an issue if `readAll()` is clearing the buffer while it is simultaneously writing to it? I was working under the assumption that QIODevice / QNetworkReply protected against this. If it doesn't; is there a mutex I can invoke to protect against this?

The other important thing to note is that my class is threaded, and I am running nearly a dozen threads at the same time, and hence there are a dozen `QNetworkAccessManager` objects as well as a subsequent `QNetworkReply` etc.

I had thought that perhaps `QNetworkAccessManager` had been deleted before Reply was ready to finish, but preventing this still gives me the bug.

Is my suspicion correct, or is there something else at play here?

Comment: please provide a [mre]